# Xamarin Forms errors but running fine

Tags: xamarin.forms

My new Xamarin Forms compile and runs fine.
Anyway, the XAML is full of errors (the code is underlined) and IntelliSense doesn't work :

[image: XAML code]

I'm running VS 2017. The error says that the property is not found in the type. That's strange because an application with this error typically won't run.

Here is an example of the error (in french)

[image: VS error]

Any idea on what could happen here ?

Many thanks in advance,
Julien

Comment: If you point the mouse on the underlined word does not appears some explanations? It is VS or XS?

Comment: Alessandro, I updated my post to answer your questions.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild? or delete manually bin and obj folders?

Comment: Yes, many times.

Comment: Try this right click on xaml file -> open with -> select Source Code(Text) Editor or Editor with encoding.

Comment: @Mounika, it's not better :(

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the application from scratch and now it's working.
Mysteries of computer science ...